# Error in compiling hello world in c

Tags: c

I am a beginner in learning c although I took two java courses at school. I just started learning c with "The C Programming" book.

I am trying to compile my first program, "hello.c"

I typed in as the book says:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

However, it says that I have to write the type specifier 'int' before main().
I'm trying to understand why this is so because the book dosen't indicate about the type specifier.

Thank you!

Comment: `int main()`  instead of `main()`.  Likewise add a `return 0;` statement after the `printf` line.

Comment: Get yourself a better book. The ISO standard mandates that `main` must return an `int`. Later versions of the standard remove the requirement to explicitly return zero but I think that was a mistake myself, and prefer to stay explicit :-)

Comment: Ok! then should I do so for all the examples in the book?

Comment: What compiler are you using? What version of C are you compiling for?

Comment: @paxdiablo thank you! it helps!

Comment: If your book is instructing you that what you have is a valid C program, it's time to get a new book. I suspect you have an old book that emphasizes K&R C style.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I'm using XCode and gcc (automatically included with XCode installation?)

Comment: @selbie thank you.. I think I'll do that..

Comment: The C Programming Language is a fantastic book, but it's really out of date. It hasn't had an update since C89.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `main` function needs to return something, that's what the compiler is telling you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello, world\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`EXIT_SUCCESS` is defined in `stdlib`. It means that the application successfully ended. Its value is usually 0.